# Cart + Checkout issues

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, integration, shopping-cart

So, this is pretty long, sorry in beforehand and hope you will try to help me anyway,

Here it goes:

I've made a custom shopping cart, and and i'm going to integrate a checkout (klarna),
the problem i have is that i try to send the items to the checkout using a json:

```
 $sendInfo = base64_encode(json_encode($_SESSION['cart_array']));
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="info" id="info" value="'.$sendInfo.'"/>';


 And to pick it up i use another one:
 $info = (array) json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['info'])); var_dump($info);
```

Which gives:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'item_id' => string '7' (length=1)
  public 'quantity' => int 1
1 => 
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'item_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 'quantity' => int 1

 So to build it further and to get the products out from the database:

 $cartOutput ="";
 $cartTotal ="";
 $cartTOTAL ="";
 $shipping ="";
 $include ="";


 if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
   $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Din kundvagn är tom</h2>";
   } else {

//Starta for each loop
$i = 0; 
   foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblproducts WHERE idProducts='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $product_name = $row["strName"];
        $price = $row["dbPrice"];
        $details = $row["strDescription"];
        $artnummer = $row["strArtnummer"];

    }
```

and with this being placed in the array for the integration:

```
 $cart = array(
  array(
    'reference' => $artnummer,
    'name' => $product_name,
    'quantity' => $each_item['quantity'],
    'unit_price' => $price,
    'discount_rate' => 0,
    'tax_rate' => $tax,
   ),
   array(
    'type' => 'shipping_fee',
    'reference' => $artnummer,
    'name' => 'Shipping Fee',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'unit_price' => $shipping,
    'tax_rate' => $tax,
)
   );

 foreach($cart as $fieldarray){
   $body .= $fieldarray['reference'].' - '. $fieldarray['name'].' - '. $fieldarray['quantity'].' - '. $fieldarray['unit_price']; 
 }
```

I get the array:

```
  //$cart var_dump
 array (size=2)
 0 => 
array (size=6)
  'reference' => string '40719013' (length=8)
  'name' => string 'Socka 2 par/fp WS Cotton' (length=24)
  'quantity' => int 1
  'unit_price' => int 4800
  'discount_rate' => int 0
  'tax_rate' => int 2500
 1 => 
array (size=6)
  'type' => string 'shipping_fee' (length=12)
  'reference' => string '40719013' (length=8)
  'name' => string 'Shipping Fee' (length=12)
  'quantity' => int 1
  'unit_price' => int 14500
  'tax_rate' => int 2500

 // $body var_dump
  string '40719013 - Socka 2 par/fp WS Cotton - 1 - 480040719013 - Shipping Fee - 1 - 14500' (length=81)
```

So far it's working good, no problems seen, and if i add quantity in the cart and then walks to the checkout, it works as well, but as some might have noticed from the first var_dump, i had two items in the cart (2 different items_id's)!
So it only shows 1 item from the cart (last one added) so the sum is wrong and all items are not listed in the checkout..

So anyone knows what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you set your $cart-Array you overwrite any previous entries:

```
$cart = array(...)
```

You probably want to add each entry to the cart-Array

```
$cart[] = array(...)
```

Comment: I've tried your tip, but i don't seem to get it to work, i end up with an empty string and when i try to add them all under one array i only get the shipping part registered, I'm starting to wonder if it's something wrong with this test module that klarna has given me, it looks like i can't show multiple products for some reason. Or is it me?